# Plot a function using Octave

Tags: plot, octave, figure

I am new to GNU Octave and I want to plot the function `psi` in the range of `[0 : 2000]`:

```
function y = H(x)
  if (x > 0)
    y = 1
  else
    y = 0
  endif
endfunction

function y = psi(s)
  t = 200
  phiabs = 500
  K = 1000
  n0 = 1000
  y = -n0 * e .^ (-(s - phiabs) / t) * H(s - phiabs) - K * H(s) * H(phiabs - s)
endfunction
```

How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "print"? Display the values on the command line? Plot it in a figure?

Comment: Plot in a figure!

Comment: `plot ~= print`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you'll want to modify your `psi` and `H` functions to be able to perform [element-wise operations](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Octave_Programming_Tutorial/Vectors_and_matrices#Element_operations) so that you can pass an array of `s` values to it and receive an array of `y` values

```
function y = H(x)
    y = double(x > 0);
endfunction

function y = psi(s)
  t = 200
  phiabs = 500
  K = 1000
  n0 = 1000
  y = -n0 * exp(-(s - phiabs) ./ t) .* H(s - phiabs) - K .* H(s) .* H(phiabs - s)
endfunction
```

Also note that instead of `e.^()` you'll need to use [`exp`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Exponents-and-Logarithms.html#XREFexp).

Then you'll want to use [`plot`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.0/Two_002dDimensional-Plots.html) to plot the result in a figure

```
s = 0:2000;
y = psi(s);

plot(s, y)
```